# SQL sorting on calculated value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help sorting an report created with an SQL query.

```
    select (CASE WHEN I4220 = '1' OR I4225='VDRRTN' then 'High' else 'Normal' END) 'Priority', i4224 'Arrived', GETDATE() - Inventory.I4224 'Days in Lab Status',i4201 'Asset', i4202 'Mfg', i4203 'Model', i4204 'Description', i4218 'Loc', i4225 'Status', 
I4214 'Lab', I4205 'LNO', I4299 'State', (CASE WHEN I4223 like '%IN%' THEN 'IN' else 'DIRECT' END) 'Overhead', I4251 'Need By Date'
from Inventory
where (i4299 in ('A','I'))and
    (i4225 in ('DEPVDRTN', 'FLOORCAL', 'LAB', 'VDRRTN'))  AND I4240 != 'SV_F35'
order by I4220 DESC, i4224 ASC;
```

I would like to sort the results of the query by 'Priority' but the priority is set to "High" based on a case statement.

```
select (CASE WHEN I4220 = '1' OR I4225='VDRRTN' then 'High' else 'Normal' END)
```

I want all items marked "High" to be on the top of the report, then I want it sorted by date in ascending order.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Justin.

Comment: Depending on the capabilities of your RDBMS, it may be as easy as `ORDER BY (CASE /* stuff ...*/ END)`

Comment: Tagged with MySQL because of `getdate()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference the column alias in the `order by` clause:

```
select (CASE WHEN I4220 = '1' OR I4225='VDRRTN' then 'High' else 'Normal' END) as Priority,
       i4224 as Arrived, GETDATE() - Inventory.I4224 `Days in Lab Status`,
       i4201 as Asset, i4202 as Mfg, i4203 as Model, i4204 as Description, i4218 as Loc,
       i4225 as Status, I4214 as Lab, I4205 as LNO, I4299 as State,
       (CASE WHEN I4223 like '%IN%' THEN 'IN' else 'DIRECT' END) as Overhead,
       I4251 as `Need By Date`
from Inventory
where (i4299 in ('A','I'))and
      (i4225 in ('DEPVDRTN', 'FLOORCAL', 'LAB', 'VDRRTN'))  AND I4240 <> 'SV_F35'
order by Priority, i4224 ASC;
```

More importantly, you should not use single quotes for identifiers.  In MySQL you can use backticks, if escaping the names is needed.  For most of your names, this is unnecessary.  Only using single quotes for string and date constants will prevent future errors.

Similarly, using `as` for column aliases is a good idea.  That way, a stray comma won't cause problems in your `select` clause.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this worked nicely. I was trying to do this already but I was using the single quotes in the order by.

Comment: @justin . . . Now you know why they are a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can either repeat the calculation in the order by:

```
select (CASE WHEN I4220 = '1' OR I4225='VDRRTN' then 'High' else 'Normal' END) 'Priority', i4224 'Arrived', GETDATE() - Inventory.I4224 'Days in Lab Status',i4201 'Asset', i4202 'Mfg', i4203 'Model', i4204 'Description', i4218 'Loc', i4225 'Status', 
I4214 'Lab', I4205 'LNO', I4299 'State', (CASE WHEN I4223 like '%IN%' THEN 'IN' else 'DIRECT' END) 'Overhead', I4251 'Need By Date'
from Inventory
where (i4299 in ('A','I'))and
    (i4225 in ('DEPVDRTN', 'FLOORCAL', 'LAB', 'VDRRTN'))  AND I4240 != 'SV_F35'
  order by (CASE WHEN I4220 = '1' OR I4225='VDRRTN' then 'High' else 'Normal' END) ASC;
```

Or you can wrap the query to calculate it once (at least in TSQL):

```
Select * from (
select (CASE WHEN I4220 = '1' OR I4225='VDRRTN' then 'High' else 'Normal' END) 'Priority', i4224 'Arrived', GETDATE() - Inventory.I4224 'Days in Lab Status',i4201 'Asset', i4202 'Mfg', i4203 'Model', i4204 'Description', i4218 'Loc', i4225 'Status', 
    I4214 'Lab', I4205 'LNO', I4299 'State', (CASE WHEN I4223 like '%IN%' THEN 'IN' else 'DIRECT' END) 'Overhead', I4251 'Need By Date'
    from Inventory
    where (i4299 in ('A','I'))and
        (i4225 in ('DEPVDRTN', 'FLOORCAL', 'LAB', 'VDRRTN'))  AND I4240 != 'SV_F35'
) x
order by 'Priority' ASC;
```

Comment: This assumes 'high' and 'normal' are your only priorities.  'h' comes before 'n' and thus sorting by priority ascending should work for you.

Comment: +1 for wrapping the query.  Having the same condition in two places is asking for trouble, especially if you need to edit it later.

Comment: Thanks for your response ps2goat. I went with Gordon's answer because it was closer to what I already had.

Comment: @Justin, that's ok.  You said you wanted to order by priority, not the other columns AND priority, so that's why I left off the other columns.